Global React Native Component in Native Android App Without an Activity or View?
I am working on a native Android project that we want to use React Native for a pretty unique workflow that there doesn't appear to be much documentation, if any on. So this would be a RN component inside of a native, already-build Android application.
The general goal is to have a RN component or module that runs in the background of the application without rendering any views, but relying on this module for some data modification and OTA updates.
The application architecture currently has a multi-activity setup: Splash -> (onboarding if needed) -> a generic activity with a drawer layout (single instance, used for display of most things in the app) -> a detail activity with just the up button. This RN component would need to be initialized close to application start and exist throughout the app lifecycle to be able to take in data and output data via callbacks.
I'm finding that without being attached to an Activity, React Native isn't functioning at times.
Has anyone ever dealt with this, or know how to make this work?
